# php script stops with no errors

Tags: php, mysqli, wamp

I use WAMP on my local pc and I'm running a php script that performs a large loop
that call a recursive function.

I defined all of the timeout and memory parameters in the php.ini and my.ini, 
but my script always stoped after a number of iterations with no errors.

I tried:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', E_ALL);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', -1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', -1);             
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

I also tried flush options, but it only got me a few more iterations.

I checked if it's a timeout problem, but I add a sleep(1) before executing the recursive function and the script stoped after the same loop iterations.

On my server I didn't have that problem, but I cann't run this script on the server because it consumed a lot of memory after some time.
My pc php version is 5.5.12 and on my server is 5.4

phpinfo xdebug section:

```
xdebug

xdebug support  enabled
Version 2.2.6
IDE Key GUY-LI-LT$

Supported protocols Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level    8000    8000
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  c:/wamp/tmp c:/wamp/tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%t.%p    cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    Off Off
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir \   \
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

Comment: do you have xdebug enabled locally?

Comment: Have you test  to run your script in command line ?

Comment: Have you check your php.log file for more details?

Comment: Hi i downloaded now xdebug, but i'm not sure how to use it. i didn't try to run the script in command line, because i can run it in the browser from my server, so i think that i can do that in my local pc. the php.log has no errors

Comment: please add a page with `<?php phpinfo() ?>` and search the output for `xdebug`. AFAIK wamp should have it installed by default. I have an hunch on a possible cause but I'd wish to have a confirm

Comment: Hey guys!! I think he is saying that he does not have the problem on his WAMP setup locally. He has the problem on his Hosted server. So fixes for WAMP are not going to help

Comment: i have to say that the solution is to setup your development server with the same versions of Apache/PHP/MySQL that you have on the Server. Then make sure you have the same config settings for each of these as well. You will then be able to see what is causing the problem because you can use relevent tools to identify the issue, which you normally cannot on a hosted server

Comment: It sounds like a segmentation fault due to PHP running out of memory. This won't produce a visible error because the PHP process has died (so it can't report the error). Apparently this is by design too. Increase the allocated memory to PHP or switch to a BFS-type algorithm if you're running a search.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

instead of

```
ini_set('display_errors', E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you good, your goal is to run script until it's done:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);//no time limit
```

Or you can do the same thing with:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Also restart wamp because if you make changes in php.ini file changes will occur after restart.

Answer (score 0):

If it stops after the same amount of iterations, most likely it's XDebug killing the script because the nesting level is too big.
Please double check [its settings](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings) inside your php.ini file, option **xdebug.max_nesting_level**

Comment: Actually he probably ( almost definitely) does not have xdebug on the live server. That output is from a WAMPServer install so I assume that is his local testing server and not the LIVE server where his problems exist!